# How to make a DataFrame column keeps not changed when you merge it with another using it as pivot

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to make that the col1 from df1 keeps with three "a" after do the merge with df2 and bring all the information from the rest of columns to the new dataframe.

To show the problem:

```
dt1 = pd.DataFrame({"col1": ["a","a", "a", "b", "c"], "col2": ["whatever", "whatever1", "whatever2", "whatever3", "whatever4"] })
dt2 = pd.DataFrame({"col1": ["a","a", "a", "b", "c"], "col3": ["w", "1", "w2", "w3", "w4"]})
dt3 = dt1.merge(dt2, on = "col1", how = "left")
```

The resul I dont like is

```
col1  col2  col3

col       col2     col3
a       whatever        w
a       whatever        1
a       whatever        w2
a       whatever1       w
a       whatever1       1
a       whatever1       w2
a       whatever2       w
a       whatever2       1
a       whatever2       w2
b       whatever3       w3
c       whatever4       w4
```

The result I´m searching for:

```
col1     col2      col3
 a      whatever    w
 a      whatever1   1
 a      whatever2   w2
 b      whatever3   w3
 c      whatever4   w4
```

Comment: `dt1.merge(dt2, left_on=["col1",dt1.index],right_on=["col1",dt2.index],how='left').drop('key_1',1)` ?